# Designing a Chart that expands as more data is entered in Excel

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2010, vba

I have a worksheet that pulls data from another, it is designed to only show late jobs, and it works perfectly. I have it where it is broken down into quarters, and it gathers all this data and does everything I want.

I have it where it shows charts, there is data in said area the chart would self populate, otherwise it would be blank. If more data is entered into the range expands the chart accordingly.

Attached is a simplified workbook with the solution.  This may not be the most eloquent way of doing it, but it works.

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/PAERTO2_1.xlsm

Comment: Can you post some sample data that is feeding the chart?

Comment: Sure, here is the sheet.https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/PAERTO2.xlsm

Comment: BTW, the data is in Q3 in this case. Each Quarter is going to have three charts based off of date. Each section the Late and Open are going to be the numbers, the dates are going to be on the bottom of the chart.  Hope this makes sense.

Comment: I'm afraid you'll need to explain which ranges feed the chart. I can't figure it out from looking at this workbook. It sounds like dynamic range names is what you need, but I can't be specific without more information.

Comment: Ok, there is a sheet that I'm not showing that feeds the data into B3, B4, E3, E4, H3, H4. I made those into values only for the sheet, those can be changed. You run the script and the information will be pushed into the last cells of J:P. Q:R reference BB:BG. U:V says how many are in each Quarter. From there cells Y:AZ look Cells Q:X and shows the correct data depending which Quarter they represent. I want to take the final data in each quarter and create three charts based off each Quarter. Each one stating the open and late jobs of each. So in reality we can use AM:AS to create the charts.

Comment: Just because I ran out of space, but the AM:AS is the final data for the charts. Three chars are going to be made from here.  AM:AO is the first, AM, AP:AQ, it the second, and AM, AR:AS is the third. What I need is each time the script is run, that the charts will update so the newest data is residing in the correct ones. I hope this clarifies things more.

Comment: Ok, I some how mysteriously seems to of solved it myself....https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3327208/Excel/PAERTO2_1.xlsm Check out Q3.

Comment: Literally... Oy! Time for some rum and Coke-Cola when I get home.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used named ranges:

- [office.microsoft.com](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/using-named-ranges-to-create-dynamic-charts-in-excel-HA001109801.aspx)  (Scroll down 2/3 for relevant information)
- [www.gilliganondata.com](http://www.gilliganondata.com/index.php/2010/08/17/excel-dynamic-named-ranges-never-manually-updating-your-charts-2/)

This may also be referred to as **Structured References**.  From Excel 2010 Help:

> Structured references make it much easier and more intuitive to work
>   with table data when you are using formulas that reference a table –
>   either portions of a table or the entire table.  They are especially
>   useful because table data ranges often change, and the cell references
>   for structured references adjust automatically.  This minimizes the
>   need to rewrite formulas as rows and columns are added and deleted in
>   a table, or when external data is refreshed.

### Update

I haven't used these techniques with Excel 2010 VBA, and the methods and keywords do seem to have changed.  I found this [hopefully helpful article](http://www.jkp-ads.com/articles/excel2007tablesvba.asp) (see section on "Inserting rows and columns").

Comment: I'm sorry, but where exactly am I looking? Because I don't see what I am looking for exactly...because the person in question in the 2nd one is showing a report range, I don't want a report range (within a set amount of data), I want it where the data expands the range...as far as I can tell.

Comment: Yes, those are different things.  Go to the first link (microsoft) and scroll down two thirds ("Plotting new data automatically").  There is the relevant part about named ranges.  If you aren't familiar with named ranges, you are in for a pleasant new experience.

Comment: Actually not really, I am attempting to figure out HOW to use this... and I'm lost. My version of excel doesn't show a "Series" tab. I'm familiar with name ranges, and the reason I am not using them is because the range of data changes... I can't dictate a range without knowing how the end user is going to use this sheet.

Comment: Okay.  Well, ignore the stuff about Series ... that article from MS focused on that, I apologize for not orienting you better.  Have you tried the Gilligan On Data page?  I believe it's more directly relevant.  I really think this is your solution!  A named range accommodates data appends, in my experience.

Comment: @MattRidge, note that the MSDN article refers to "dynamic names."  These are named ranges that grow with your data.  A search for "excel chart dynamic named ranges" will get lots of helpful results.

Comment: Did I forget to mention I am using Excel 2010?

Comment: You should post at least a summary of the concepts found on those pages. Link-only answers are subject to link rot.

Comment: Check out this link http://peltiertech.com/Excel/Charts/DynamicColumnChart1.html it breaks it down for you.

Comment: @JimmyPena -- well said, and I will improve

Comment: @Matt Ridge -- Your mention of 2010 may be important.  There may have been a shift of nomenclature.  Thus 'structured references' will give you more to work with.

Comment: Ok, Here is the issue I am having. All of these chars require manual manipulation to add "another line" the way I have it is that the Excel Sheet I am using is using Excel VBA to populate the row under the data... so this means that the data will not be self populated, because it will never recognize the creation of a new row because a person will never enter it.  Does this make sense?

Comment: That makes sense, yes.  See my update above, specific to Excel 2007/2010.

Comment: @MattRidge - I think the link in Jesse's comment above is your best answer. It's a tried and true method I've used for a long time. I don't have 2010, but I would think it is transferable. The method on that link will capture all new data added to as an additional row / column, either manually or threw VBA manipulation. If you need help implementing it let me know.

Comment: @Scott I have been playing with the sheet, and I keep getting stuck...but it's not where I thought I would, but at the same time I did things a little differently at the get go too, so I can't use everything they are telling me to use either. If you can help it be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I figured out something, for the concept I am working with, the link Jesse linked to, won't work for me. I require multiple table dependent on lines of data that overlap.

Comment: Well, it seems like it is kind of confusing what you are trying to do. I've found the simplest way to work with spreadsheets is to break them up into components. I have no idea what `I require multiple table dependent on lines of data that overlap` means, but if you want to chart something, just have a one source range for your chart - use formulas or whatever you need to get the data you need charted, then base your chart on that data.